# Instantiate child class with values of existing parent class

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, casting

I want to transfer the values of an existing parent class to a new child. If possible without reflection.
Another possible solution could be if I could "cast" the class to the child class.

This is a simplified example of what I want to achieve.

```
open class Dog {
    var height = -1
}

class Dalmatian: Dog() {
    var dots = -1
}

fun main() {
    val dog: Any = Dog().apply {
        height = 24
    }
    
    // Doesn't work
    val dalmatian = (dog as Dalmatian).apply {
        dots = 101
    }
}
```

Comment: Frame challenge: can you prevent it creating a superclass (Dog) instance in the first place, and create the subclass (Dalmatian) directly? Does Dalmatian need to be a subclass of Dog, or can you use composition or delegation instead (i.e wrapping/using the Dog instance)? — As Jorn shows, there's no easy way to do this, and I suspect there may be a different approach which would work better.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to convert classes to a subtype. In your case, you could just make a method:

```
class Dog(var height: Int = -1)
class Dalmation(height: Int = -1, var dots: Int = 24): Dog(height) {
  companion object {
    fun fromDog(dog: Dog, dots: Int) = Dalmation(dog.height, dots)
  }
}
```

You can then convert:

```
fun main() {
  val dog = Dog()
  val dalmation = Dalmation.fromDog(dog, 24)
}
```

and you can cast only if the Dog is already a Dalmation:

```
fun main() {
  val dog: Dog = Dalmatian()
  val dalmatian: Dalmatian = dog as Dalmatian
  
  // but not this
  val dalmatian: Dalmatian = Dog() as Dalmatian
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The actual superclass has a ton of variables so your solution would be a pain to implement. I think I'll rather go with reflection.